# Simplify a code

Tags: excel, vba

The first part of the code works very well, but can I make it more simple, something like the second code? I have tried the second, but excel returns "Run-time error 1004 - Application-defined or object-defined error".

```
            Worksheets(sample).Range("ratio143144").Copy
            Worksheets("Results").Activate
            Range("D" & inserir.Row).Select
            ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial Link:=True

            Worksheets(sample).Range("ratio146144").Copy
            Worksheets("Results").Range("I" & inserir).PasteSpecial Link:=True
```

---

GolezTrol, I tried to use inserir.row, but excel keeps returning the same error. Below, the complete code. Do you have any suggestion?

Sub CopiarOriginais()

```
    Dim Certeza As VbMsgBoxResult
    Dim sample As String
    Dim inserir As Range


        ActiveSheet.Name = Range("Y1").Value
        sample = Range("Y1").Value

    Certeza = MsgBox("Você tem certeza de que os dados originais já não foram copiado? Utilizar novamente essa função, após o teste 2-sigma ter sido aplicado, comprometerá os seus dados originais.", vbYesNo)

        If Certeza = vbNo Then End

        Sheets("Results").Activate
        Range("B2").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Select
        Set inserir = ActiveCell




        Sheets(sample).Activate

        Range("B3:D122").Copy
        Range("B132").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        Application.CutCopyMode = False



        Worksheets(sample).Range("ratio143144").Copy

            Worksheets("Results").Activate
            Range("D" & inserir.Row).Select
            ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial Link:=True

        Worksheets(sample).Range("ratio146144").Copy

            Worksheets("Results").Activate
            Range("I" & inserir.Row).Select
            ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial Link:=True

'        Worksheets("Results").Range("I" & inserir.Row).PasteSpecial Link:=True

        Worksheets(sample).Range("ratio145144").Copy
        Worksheets("Results").Range("G" & inserir.Row).PasteSpecial Link:=True

        Worksheets(sample).Range("ratio1431442se").Copy
        Worksheets("Results").Range("F" & inserir).PasteSpecial Link:=True

        Worksheets(sample).Range("ratio1451442se").Copy
        Worksheets("Results").Range("H" & inserir).PasteSpecial Link:=True

        Worksheets(sample).Activate


    Range("A1").Select

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

The second should work just fine, I think, but you're using `"I"` instead of `"D"` in the range. Also, you're using `inserir` instead of `inserir.Row`. So I think it's just a simple error like that. Theoretically it should work fine.